Mapbox Navigation V3 - No method for displaying [NavigationRoute]?
Not getting much help from Mapbox people, wondering if someone else has had this issue. I am trying to display an array of routes on Mapbox. I used to use the method NavigationMap.show([route1, route2]) but now it is navigationMapView.show(<#T##navigationRoutes: NavigationRoutes##NavigationRoutes#>, routeAnnotationKinds: <#T##Set<RouteAnnotationKind>#>).
The updated method now takes NavigationRoutes instead of an array of routes. NavigationRoutes contains a main route and alternate routes to the same destination. However I need to display two routes to two different destinations.
I am generating the route like so:
let userWaypoint = Waypoint(
                location: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude),
                name: "user"
            )
            let destinationWaypoint = Waypoint(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destination.latitude, longitude: destination.longitude))
            let navigationRouteOptions = NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [userWaypoint, destinationWaypoint])
            let task = mapboxNavigation.routingProvider().calculateRoutes(options: navigationRouteOptions)
            Task { [weak self] in
                switch await task.result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                case .success(let response):
                    guard let self else { return }
                    
                    // I used to add the new route to an array and then show the routes 
                    // but this no longer works
                    //routes.append(response.mainRoute)
                    //navigationMapView.show(routes)
                      
                    navigationRoutes = response
                }
            }

And then like in the mapbox tutorial:
var navigationRoutes: NavigationRoutes? {
        didSet {
            showCurrentRoute()
        }
    }

    func showCurrentRoute() {
        guard let navigationRoutes else {
            return
        }
        navigationMapView.showcase(navigationRoutes)
    }

Every time showcase is called, removeRoutes() is also called so I can not show multiple navigationRoutes. Anyone have a solution to this or do I need to edit the mapbox method?
